# Creating a SQL trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger on my database, using SQL, such that after an insert into the table `HISTORY` table, if, the attribute `FINISHED="T"`, the `MESSAGE` attribute is `"FINISHED"` else, if `FINISHED="F"`, the `MESSAGE` is `"NOT FINISHED"`.

This is my code currently when I try to run this, it says

> "Trigger created with compilation errors"

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with this statement? Thank you!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MESSAGE_TR
AFTER INSERT
ON HISTORY
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (HISTORY.FINISHED="T")
    THEN
        INSERT INTO HISTORY(MESSAGE) VALUES("FINISHED");
    ELSEIF (HISTORY.FINISHED="F")
        INSERT INTO HISTORY(MESSAGE)VALUES("NOT FINISHED");
END;
/
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? That code won't run on both of them.

Comment: @jarlh I am using Oracle.

Comment: I would start with single quotes around the string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you intend:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MESSAGE_TR
BEFORE INSERT
ON HISTORY
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :NEW.MESSAGE := (CASE WHEN :NEW.FINISHED = 'T' THEN 'FINISHED' ELSE 'NOT FINISHED' END);
END;
```

Note that this is a *before* insert trigger, because it intends to modify the row being inserted.